Google PlayConsole do tests with untrusted devices so PlayIntegrity checks fail
I implemented PlayIntegrity in my App to check the license (App downloaded from GooglePlay) and device integrity (not rooted device and a trust one by Google).
If one of these check fail, I open my GooglePlay App page so the user can download the official version.
The problem occurs when I need to publish an update of my App on Google PlayConsole: here, even pre-launch tests are all passed, the next review step done by Google fails because they use virtual devices or a version of my App not downloaded from GooglePlay so the PlayIntegrity licence check fails, correctly!
But in this case, PlayConsole reject my update with the reason "Your app contains content that isn't compliant with the Broken Functionality policy: App loads, but not responsive".
So, how can I use PlayIntegrity without make the Google tests fail?
There is something that I need to do programmatically?

Could you put the whole message, and the screenshot from the review if possible

@user16930239 the screenshot was a white screen with the app icon at its center.

I have a similar experience with something close to your problem, and I would fix it this way:

I would not "open Google Play App page" immediately, I would show a message for the user to tell them that the device is not trusted or the app version is not installed properly, and would ask them to go Google pLay official app and provide the link via an action (button that redirect user to Google play app)
If Google Play still reject your app, there is a new support method in Google Play (I've tried it and it is great) which is Get a call from Google (Check the image below) they will call you immediately and provide professional help within 48 hours. and usually they will Help you in more efficient way than the usually routes. you can access this from Google play console, click on the question mark icon at the upper right corner, then Click on contact us form.


Note: even though they listed supported countries they can call anyone outside these countries.
I am positive that this will solve your problem. Good luck

thanks a lot, I'll try this way and I'll update here

Thanks, the not "open Google Play App page" option works!

@user2342558 that's great
